quemu-guest-agent not starting after reboot
I spun up 3 new VMs this weekend, 2 Debian headless servers and 1 Mint-Cinnamon desktop VM.  For all 3 of them, the qemu-guest-agent will not start automatically and I have to manually run systemctl start qemu-guest-agent to get it started.  The other 6 VMs that I built in the past do not have this issue.  I have tried enabling the qemu-guest-agent, and I get this result:
# systemctl enable qemu-guest-agent
Synchronizing state of qemu-guest-agent.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable qemu-guest-agent
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling qemu-guest-agent but get the same results.  Any ideas?

The error message seems quite comprehensive. Can you sucessfully start the unit manually (systemctl start qemu-guest-agent)? You could add the necessary [Install] section by editing the unit configuration.

Yes, I can start it manually.  From what I have read about the qemu-guest-agent, it is supposed to start based on a probe from the proxmox.  It works automatically on all of my other VMs except for the 3 I created last weekend (the others, I created months ago).  I did not have to edit the unit configuration for any of the older VMs.

I tried manually running qm set VMID --agent enabled=1 from the command line on the VMs even though the agent was Enabled in the GUI and it seems to have worked.  Kinda annoying that setting it in the GUI didn't work.  I noticed in the config file for the VMs, it said agent: 1 but now says agent: enabled=1.  The old VMs that were working fine all say agent: 1.  Baffling.
